# What kind of technology is used to create this "The Self Balancing Electric Motorcycle"?

Tags: motorcycle

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPyIwY2hJ_A) , the commentator said that the vehicle uses some kind of technology to keep the Motorcycle self-balanced. That means it won't fall over even with an outside impact force.

Since my English is not very good, I could not hear the name of the technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vehicle uses 2 [GYROSCOPES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) as seen [here](https://youtu.be/kPyIwY2hJ_A?t=44s) (same video) to stabilize the vehicle.
Read up a little about the concept on the first link.
The key property that is being exploited here is the gyroscopic couple formation.
A torque applied perpendicular to the axis of rotation of a spinning disc, and therefore perpendicular to the angular momentum vector, results in a rotation about an axis perpendicular to both the applied torque and Angular momentum. This would result in a motion called gyroscopic precession. <- this can be seen in the video when the person tries to topple the bike - notice the axis around which the discs automatically swivel. The discs , in this case are rotating in opposite orientations.
I failed to find intuitive videos explaining this, but here's one anyhow - [Solving the Mystery of Gyroscopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUgwaKebHTs)
You have encountered the effect of gyroscopes when you roll a tire (or ride a bike).
Notice how it's easy to balance a rolling wheel? The rolling wheel is effectively a gyroscope. The weight of the wheel, which effectively provides an unsettling torque depending on which side the wheel is leaning towards, will cause the wheel to turn instead of falling.
I've written this in haste, and would urge you to read up on the fundamentals (Rotational Mechanics) before delving on the admittedly non intuitive effects.